# Update an HTML div using Javascript without refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to make a simple rating system using php and javascript .
the idea is to change the value of HTML div (number of rate) using javascript without refreshing the page , the problem is that i can't get the value of the HTML div .
this is the div :

```
<div id="rating" >5565</div>
```

and i try to get this value using javascript

```
function give_id_like() {
    var a = document.getElementById("rating").value;
    var c = a + 1;
    document.getElementById("rating").innerHTML = c;
}
```

but i get this result, for example if i have in the div 88 when i run the function i get this 881 if i run it again i get 8811 .
what i want is when i run the function i want to get 89 and when i run it again 90 and so on .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens because `value` property returns String object. You need [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) for this:

```
c = parseInt( a, 10 ) + 1;
```

Comment: @didyeg because you need to use `innerHTML`, not `value` in `document.getElementById("rating").value`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `parseInt()`

```
function give_id_like() {
    var a = parseInt(document.getElementById("rating").value);
    var c = a + 1;
    document.getElementById("rating").innerHTML = c;
}
```

Comment: You should always specify the base when using parseInt.